# How to go about debugging SystemJS issues?

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I have an AngularJS 2.0 app written in TypeScript that uses the SystemJS loader. When I run the app I get the following 404 error:

```
404 GET /node_modules/ponyfill/package.json
```

Now as far as I can tell, no module has a dependency on `ponyfill`. I have other AngularJS apps with similar setups that are working just fine. But I cannot figure out what's the difference with this app. How would you approach debugging such an issue? Are there any tools?

P.S. I found a tools called [SystemJS Debugger](https://github.com/peteruithoven/systemjs-debugger) but the documentation is not very clear.

P.S. My SystemJS configuration looks like this:

```
System.config({
    "defaultJSExtensions": true,
    "packageConfigPaths": [
        "/node_modules/*/package.json"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "main": "/main",
        "angular2/*": "/angular2/*",
        "rxjs/*": "/rxjs/*",
        "app/*": "/app/*",
        "*": "/node_modules/*"
    },
    "packages": {
        "angular2": {
            "defaultExtension": false
        },
        "rxjs": {
            "defaultExtension": false
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit**

I found that `packageConfigPaths` in the configuration above was causing the problem. It's the one that makes SystemJS go haywire and start looking for `package.json` files at runtime. If I remove it the issue goes away. I did not find `packageConfigPaths` documented anywhere. Anyone know what it does. I had simply copied it from a template.

**Edit 2**

I have put my full application on Github so that anyone can reproduce this issue. The repository is https://github.com/archfirst/angular2-minimal-app. The application should built perfectly fine with the checked-in code. To reproduce the issue, simply edit index.html and uncomment `packageConfigPaths` and `paths` properties of the SystemJS configuration.

Answer (score 1):

looks like typo, try to rename ponyfill to polyfill

Comment: Definitely not a typo. I look through the node_modules packages and there are several instance of the word. Also you can google for it.

Comment: put here package.json

Comment: Please see my Edit 2. I have made the full project available so that you can reproduce the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem recently. The solution (as of Angular RC 1) was to include rxjs **AFTER** System:

```html
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

After re-arranging these script tags, the problem was resolved. Hope this helps.